# DDD bounded context service vs database integration

Tags: domain-driven-design, integration, bounded-contexts

2 bounded contexts, first is "Product catalog", second is "Marketing".

Marketing context depends on Product catalog.

Marketing needs specific data from the product catalog. I hesitate between 2 approaches:

1 - Keep the data in the product catalog, create a service interface in the product catalog that would be for the unique purpose of querying data for the marketing specific use case.

2- Have a process that will query data from the product catalog database, and transfer only the needed information (plus make any model translation needed) into the marketing database.

Note that the marketing context does not really need to have real time fresh data from the catalog, and I don't want to address performance issues for now either.

I like the first option because it seems simpler, but I don't like it because I'm not sure if it is really a good practice to design services specifically for the use of another context use case ? 
It seems to me like a leak of the marketing's context logic into the product catalog logic and I fear of multiplying services for many other depending contexts and use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Product Catalog (PC) is upstream (US) and Marketing (M) is downstream (DS).

If I dont misundertand you, basicly you are a asking whether you should go for a sync integration (option 1) or async (2).

Since you say M doesnt need real time data from PC, maybe I should go for async integration. But I wouldnt do it through db integration, but with events:

The US context (PC) publishes events (ProductWasCreated for example) everytime there is a change in the data, and the DS context (M) would subscribe to them and react (insert the product in its db).

About approach (1), I think that there is no problem in PC offering the services that M needs. A service must serve what the clients need, it would have no sense that a bounded context would offer something that nobody wants. Anyway it all depends on the relationship between the teams (customer/supplier, partnership, ...)

You should take a look to the different types of context mapping (for example, in the red book by Vauhgn Vernon).